Add HTTP headers meant specifically for an HTTP or HTTPS proxy server in PlayWright requests, cUrl equivalent is --proxy-headers
In curl we use --proxy-header, so that the header will be used by proxy server only. This header will not be sent in http request to the target server
e.g: the request will be allowed to pass thro proxy server, only if the PROXY_HDR_NAME is provided in proxy-header.
curl doc: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--proxy-header
curl -v --include --proxy http://myproxy:8888 --proxy-header "PROXY_HDR_NAME: VALUE"

cUrl first make connect call with proxy server with provided header and creates the tunnel and then sends the request thro this tunnel.
How to do it in browser using playwright API? i.e. add HTTP headers meant specifically for an HTTP or HTTPS proxy server
I tried using page.setExtraHTTPHeaders, but it did not work.
page.route or browserContext.route does not help in this case.
Also, even if playwright provides this feature, does the brwosers e.g chrome or chromium supports this at browser level?
